# How to fix "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response" in the JS console?

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to pull data from an API, however i am receiving the following response in the console:

"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

I'm trying to run this on a local server on MAMP PRO.

my code is as follows:

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){
    console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
}
ourRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

If client and server in different domain means. in server you need to allow cors origin request by using wildcard

Comment: Many thanks for the response. How do I achieve that?

Comment: enable cors in server side.

Comment: Could you provide me with more insight please? I don't know how to do this. 

I am using MAMP PRO for a local server. 
Thanks

Comment: what's your server side language and server domain?

Comment: It says Apache and 'Dynamic DNS' ? 

I am trying to get the access the API from (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) - however this Cross Origin Blocker wont let me test the API.

Comment: so you are sending request ```https://api.binance.com``` endpoint using client side ?